# paste end of variable name based on i in for loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to save each variable save_i (up to length(counter)) as a row in a csv file. Each save variable is defined in a while loop so I have save_1:save_i where i= length(counter). A portion of the code is below:

```
# Packages
import msvcrt
import time
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import csv


# Settings
PLAY_TIME = 5  # in seconds


# Sound
sound_file_1 = 'C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_1.mp3'
sound_file_2 = 'C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_2.mp3'
blast_file_1, fs1 = sf.read(sound_file_1, dtype='float32')
blast_file_2, fs2 = sf.read(sound_file_2, dtype='float32')


# Set Up
time_start = time.perf_counter()
time_stop = time.perf_counter()
time_elapsed = time_stop - time_start
counter = 0

# Basic Logic
while time_elapsed < PLAY_TIME:
    blast = msvcrt.getch()
    if blast == b'1':
        blast = 1
        time_in = time.perf_counter()
        time_to_button_press = time_in - time_start
        sd.play(blast_file_1, device=4)
        status = sd.wait()
        time_in = time.perf_counter()
        time_to_blast_end = time_in - time_start
        counter += 1
        save = "save_"+str(counter)
        globals()[save] = (counter, blast, time_to_button_press, time_to_blast_end)
        print(eval("save_"+str(counter)))
        if time_to_blast_end > PLAY_TIME:
            break
    elif blast == b'2':
        blast = 2
        time_in = time.perf_counter()
        time_to_button_press = time_in - time_start
        sd.play(blast_file_2, device=4)
        status = sd.wait()
        time_in = time.perf_counter()
        time_to_blast_end = time_in - time_start
        counter += 1
        save = "save_"+str(counter)
        globals()[save] = (counter, blast, time_to_button_press, time_to_blast_end)
        print(eval("save_"+str(counter)))
        if time_to_blast_end > PLAY_TIME:
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")


with open('C:/Users/am650/Desktop/testdata.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for i in range(counter):
        datawriter.writerow(eval("save_"+str(i)))
```

I have tried several variations of that last line of code (`datawriter.writerow(eval("save_"+str(i)))`), but none of my attempts have worked as expected.  The above returns an empty excel sheet. `datawriter.writerow("save_"+str(i)` returns "save_1", "save_2", etc. up to length(counter) as there own rows instead of the data saved in those variables. `datawriter.writerow("save_"+str(counter))`gives me the last round of data repeated for i rows (which tells me that the for loop is working okay); additionally, this gives me the last save variable with all components (counter, blast, time_to_button_press, and time_to_blast_end) in one column separated by spaces rather than each component in its own column.

I expect the code to give me an excel sheet that looks something like:

r1: 1, 4, 0.5, 1

r2: 2, 2, 1.7, 2.3

r3: 3, 5, 4, 4.5

etc. where each row has four columns and contains the data from save_1:save_i

Any help would be great :) Please forgive my code's inelegance, I almost exclusively work in r. I have tried to use a bunch of the already answered similar questions and they have gotten me closer to my goal, but not all the way.

Comment: Oops, I'm on Windows 11, Python 3.11.0

Comment: Basically... it's the wrong thing to try to do. A more common way to do a similar thing would be instead of trying to dynamically create a bunch of global variables, have a single dictionary and add the values to that, with your desired var names as the key names.  You can then easily iterate over the dictionary later to get the values back out such as when writing your csv file

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little lost. Do you mean I should make a bunch of empty variables and then fill in a variable selected by the counter? I could do that in the while loop just fine, but I don't understand how that would help me write the csv as I would have the same arrangments of variables as I currently do... could you expand/write an example below?

Comment: You really want to look at using lists to store your data.

Comment: Any time you find yourself trying to reference a bunch of similarly-named variables, you probably want to use a collection instead - a list or a dict, depending on whether they differ by number or name. That's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had not even heard of those things until JonSG gave me the below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing a lot of work to manumatically do what a set of lists might do for you. Rather than creating a bunch of variables `foo_1`, `foo_2`, ...., `foo_n`, you probably want to use a list or dictionary to store those.

Here is how I might initially approach the problem:

```py
# Packages
import csv
import msvcrt
import time

import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

# Settings
PLAY_TIME = 5  # in seconds

# Sounds
blast_files = {
    "1": sf.read('C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_1.mp3', dtype='float32'),
    "q": sf.read('C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_q.mp3', dtype='float32'),
}
save_files = []

counter = 0
time_start = time.perf_counter()
time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start

while time_elapsed < PLAY_TIME:
    blast_key = msvcrt.getch().decode()
    if not blast_key in blast_files:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start
        continue

    counter += 1
 
    time_to_button_press = time.perf_counter() - time_start
    sd.play(blast_files[blast_key], device=4)
    status = sd.wait()
    time_to_blast_end = time.perf_counter() - time_start
 
    save_files.append([counter, blast_key, time_to_button_press, time_to_blast_end])
    time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start

with open('C:/Users/am650/Desktop/testdata.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in save_files:
        print(row)  ## just to demonstrate that row here should be an item stored it the list save_files
        datawriter.writerow(row)
```

I don't have the sound libraries but here is a version that works for me.  It accepts inputs of `1` and will print a list of files and construct the csv.

```py
# Packages
import csv
import msvcrt
import time

# Settings
PLAY_TIME = 5  # in seconds

# Sounds
blast_files = {
    "1": 'C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_1.mp3',
    "q": 'C:/Users/am650/Desktop/Audio/aaa_q.mp3',
}
save_files = []

counter = 0
time_start = time.perf_counter()
time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start

while time_elapsed < PLAY_TIME:
    blast_key = msvcrt.getch().decode()

    if not blast_key in blast_files:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start
        continue

    counter += 1
 
    time_to_button_press = time.perf_counter() - time_start
    print(blast_files[blast_key])
    time_to_blast_end = time.perf_counter() - time_start
 
    save_files.append([counter, blast_key, time_to_button_press, time_to_blast_end])
    time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start

with open('testdata.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in save_files:
        print(row)  ## just to demonstrate that row here should be an item stored it the list save_files
        datawriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: thanks for this! I can't get the code to run, though. When I open it through the terminal, it initially opens and then immediately exits (presumably with an error code somewhere but I can't see it). I use Pycharm but msvcrt does not work inside of pycharm

Comment: you will need to witch to a dictionary then... let me update the code for that.

Comment: Sorry, I had run the code wrong when I first wrote that comment. It actually won't run...

Comment: I don't have some of those packages installed so if you get an error please let me know as much of the details as you can.

Comment: With the updated code, I get "invalid entry" no matter what I press

Comment: my bad, you need to cast your keypress into a string.  `msvcrt.getch().decode()` I updated the answer to do that.

Comment: Playing around with it, I got it to recognize a keypress with b'1' and b'q' (weird msvcrt quark), but it immediately shuts down after a recognized keypress. I don't know how to see errors outside of pycharm. I tried to google it but I am getting nowhere. I can't see errors in the terminal

Comment: Same behaviour with the decode update (it immediately shuts down after a recognized keypress)

Comment: This might be obvious, but you only give yourself 5 seconds to hit the key. Could that be a problem

Comment: No, the same thing happens when I extend play_time

Comment: I'll add a version that seems to work for me (without playing the sounds)